# Autostart videostream without logging in

Tags: camera, streaming-video

I am trying to auto-start a script, that starts a video stream via vlc on a raspberry pi with raspi camera. This is the code that starts the stream:

```
raspivid -o - -t 0 -hf -w 640 -h 360 -fps 25 | cvlc -vvv stream:///dev/stdin --sout '#rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8554}' :demux=h264
```

I have tried to add the script to init.d which does work as the LED on the camera blinks, but the startup seems to stop the script after a second. I also tried to add the script to rc.local and autologin and it didn't even blink. I tried to edit /etc/bash.bashrc too, with the following code:

```
if [ $(tty) == /dev/tty1 ]; then
./script
fi
```

But that didn't work either. Any suggestions? The script runs fine on its own.

I should also add that the stream gives an output constantly and it can't be hidden or ignored.

Comment: Hi! You might try adding `sleep X`  at the beginning of `script` (where `X` is a reasonable number of seconds) and changing the line of your code into `./script &` . However, I haven't tested it, it's basically only a blind shot.

Comment: I forgot to add, use `init.d` of course, using `.bashrc` seems just wrong! The idea was simply to add a long sleep in the process.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work. The Camera does not blink or anything.

Comment: Try run from ~/.xinitrc

Comment: Try putting it in /etc/rc.local with the & after.

Comment: @hendry Where is the .xinitrc located? I can't find it in /etc/.

Comment: @Fred putting it in rc-local didn't work either :/

Comment: Is that with or without the tty1 check? If with, try without.

Comment: Tried both options and none of them worked.

Comment: The camera blinks, and then stops. It's like the script get executed, but stop after one second. Maybe there is something I can add to prevent the "consol" from stopping the script?

Comment: @hendry the xinitrc file is taken from "X Init", so only when X is initiated. I doubt Diego is starting X when he's not logging in.

Comment: @Diego: Hendry mentiond `~/.xinitrc`. Although this is not the best file for your solution, the answer to your question in reply is in there: the `~` in bash is always pointing to the current-users homedir. So when logged in as `pi` its `/home/pi`, when as `root` its `/root/`. so this file is /home/pi/.xinitrc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have now found out two solutions.

1. Making a script that run another script (This is the one I'm using
   at the moment)

I have made a script (check.sh) that searches the processes-list for "vlc", and if it get any hit it will exit the script. If there are no processes called "vlc" running, it execute a script (video.sh) which start the stream. In crontab I added the first script (check.sh) to be run when booting:

```
crontab -e @reboot /home/pi/check.sh
```

This is what check.sh looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash 
pidof='pidof vlc' if [[ -z $pidof ]] 
then
exit 
else
/home/pi/video.sh fi
exit
```

And this is what video.sh looks like:

```
raspivid -o - -t 0 -hf -w 640 -h 360 -fps 25 | cvlc -vvv
stream:///dev/stdin --sout '#rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8554}' :demux=h264 OBS!
This will not work with **sudo crontab -e** as vlc only run as
regular user (pi works fine)
```

2. Adding only execution-line into rc.local

I have not tried this, but a collegue got this to work with vlc on raspberry. This way you only have to add one string to rc.local with a pause before the string, like this:

```
(sleep 5;su - pi -c "raspivid -o - -t 0 -n -w 640 -h 480 -fps 15 | cvlc -vvv stream:///dev/stdin --sout '#rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8554/}' :demux=h264")&
```

There may be more ways to do this, but this is what I have found out so far.