# Raspberry Pi for streaming movies when TV is switched on

Tags: home-automation, streaming

My mother has Alzehmiers and finds it hard on most days to switch the TV on and watch programs. I want to use a Raspberry Pi to stream movies to her TV as soon as she switches the TV on. I can attach a Raspberry Pi to the HDMI port and and have it running and playing videos.

What is the best way to do this or are there better alternatives as I just want her to switch the TV without doing anything else?

Comment: is the Pi always on, or is it powered by a USB port on the television?

Comment: It will always be on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use VLC, with a long playlist, which starts automatically, when the Pi is powered up, using this solution, [Autostart videostream without logging in](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/14398/autostart-videostream-without-logging-in).

As [Jarmanda X suggests](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/87969/raspberry-pi-for-streaming-movies-when-tv-is-switched-on#comment139841_87969), power the Pi from the TV's USB (assuming that it has one), so that when the TV is powered on, the Pi starts as well.

---

Assuming that it would not be to confusing, as an added feature, you could get VLC to play random segments, of films in a playlist, in a random order using this Python solution, from SuperUser, [Playback random section from multiple videos changing every 5 minutes](https://superuser.com/questions/81044/playback-random-section-from-multiple-videos-changing-every-5-minutes), and refined in this thread, [Play random section from random movies in VLC?](https://forum.videohelp.com/threads/374233-Play-random-section-from-random-movies-in-VLC).

```
import subprocess
import random
import time
import os
import sys

## Just seed if you want to get the same sequence after restarting the script
random.seed()

SocketLocation = "/Users/username/vlc.sock"

## You can enter a directory as a command line argument; otherwise it will use the default
if(len(sys.argv) >= 2):
    MoviesDir = sys.argv[1]
else:
    MoviesDir = "/Users/username/Movies"

## You can enter the interval in seconds as the second command line argument as well
if(len(sys.argv) >= 3):
    IntervalInSeconds = int(sys.argv[2])
else:
    IntervalInSeconds = 10 

## Sends an arbitrary command to VLC
def RunVLCCommand(cmd):
    p = subprocess.Popen("echo " + cmd + " | nc -U " + SocketLocation, shell = True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
    errcode = p.wait()
    retval = p.stdout.read()
    print "returning: " + retval
    return retval 

## Clear the playlist
RunVLCCommand("clear")

RawMovieFiles = os.listdir(MoviesDir)
MovieFiles = []
FileLengths = []

## Loop through the directory listing and all subfolders adding each movie file found to the playlist
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(MoviesDir, topdown=False):
    for name in files:
        MovieFile = os.path.join(root, name)
        if(MovieFile.lower().endswith(".mp4") or MovieFile.lower().endswith(".mkv") or MovieFile.lower().endswith(".avi") or MovieFile.lower().endswith(".ts") or MovieFile.lower().endswith(".vob") or MovieFile.lower().endswith(".mpg") or MovieFile.lower().endswith(".flv")):
          MovieFiles.append(MovieFile)
          RunVLCCommand("add \"" + MovieFile + "\"")

PlayListItemNum = 0

## Loop forever
while 1==1:
    ## Choose a random movie from the playlist
    PlayListItemNum = random.randint(1, len(MovieFiles))
    RunVLCCommand("goto " + str(PlayListItemNum))

    FileLength = "notadigit"
    tries = 0

    ## Sometimes get_length doesn't work right away so retry 50 times
    while tries < 50 and FileLength .strip().isdigit() == False or FileLength.strip() == "0":
        tries+=1
        FileLength = RunVLCCommand("get_length")    

    ## If get_length fails 50 times in a row, just choose another movie
    if tries < 50:
        ## Choose a random duration between 20s and 45s
        IntervalInSeconds = random.randint(20,45)
        ## Choose a random start time 
        StartTimeCode = random.randint(30, int(FileLength) - IntervalInSeconds);


        RunVLCCommand("seek " + str(StartTimeCode))

        ## Turn on fullscreen
        RunVLCCommand("f on")

        ## Wait until the interval expires
        time.sleep(IntervalInSeconds)   
        ## Skip to the next movie after playing for the given random duration
        RunVLCCommand("next")   
        tries = 0
        ## Wait until the video stops playing or 50 tries, whichever comes first
        while tries < 50 and RunVLCCommand("is_playing").strip() == "1":    
            time.sleep(1) 
            tries+=1
```

This was written for a Mac, so you would probably need to change `/Users` to `/home` in order to get it to work on the Pi correctly.

You have to set up a *sock* in order to programatically control VLC, which is described here: [Controlling VLC via RC (“Remote Control”) interface using a UNIX domain socket (and no programming)](https://n0tablog.wordpress.com/2009/02/09/controlling-vlc-via-rc-remote-control-interface-using-a-unix-domain-socket-and-no-programming/).

Enable RC interface:

[image: Enable RC interface]

Configure RC interface:

[image: Configure RC interface]

You would need to change the `/Users` to the path that you use in the script for `SocketLocation`.

I have consolidated all of the steps and links in a blog, [Random VLC random clip player](https://gr33nonline.wordpress.com/2018/07/13/random-vlc-random-clip-player/). Again, this blog is for OSX, but as they are both Unix it is a simple matter of changing the necessary paths.

You could modify the script so that it doesn't play random segments, only the playlist in a random order, so that every time the TV is switched on it doesn't always start with the same sequence of movies.

Also, for the autostart up, either ensuring the `vlc` is in your `PATH` environment variable (use echo `$PATH` to verify), or using the full path to `vlc` in the startup script.

Comment: Thank you. This is the way I will go as it seems it will allow for power outages. You have given me a direction and code as well .  As i am new to all of this it will take some time to work through this but thank you to all above

Comment: Thanks  again to everyone for the suggestions. I have some limited programming experience but I should be able to wade through the above response  from Greenonline.  I have a raspberry pi and I will start playing.

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to upvote and accept any answers that you found to be useful

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can clip together a bunch of tv shows together into a single video and have it just play on a loop with any video player. as long as the pi stays on you can turn the tv off and on and the pi will always be ready to go.

Comment: Yes this is a solution but I need to make sure that if the power goes off it reboots and loads up the stream